# Geddy swig template

Tags: geddy, swig-template

Is it possible to use swig inheritance in geddy? When I'm looking at the code generated by geddy gen app app1 --swig, It looks like everything is like ejs but just changed it to {{ or {%.

Is there a documentation on how to use swig on Geddy or maybe an example.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A few issues:

1. It looks like geddy has yet to update to support swig@>=1.0
2. Geddy only supports the antiquated "layout/partials" style of rendering and does not allow for the template engines to set this up for themselves. There's an open issue at this time discussing these issues: https://github.com/mde/geddy/issues/436

Comment: Thanks for replying Paul. We'd definitely like to support Swig as it was meant to be used!

Answer (score 0):

What we have been doing with the other template engines is using the geddy `partial` helper function. This is more flexible than using the native subtemplate syntax that comes bundled with the template engines.

I was working on our Swig scaffolds a few months back and could not get `partial` to work with swig. I couldn't get it to pass the current rendering context to the sub-template, so all my variables were undefined.

This might have changed as Swig had a major update recently. If you have any luck, please let us know on GitHub or the mailing list so we can make the changes to our scaffolding code.

[Here is an example of how `partial` is used in handlebars](https://github.com/mde/geddy/blob/master/gen/scaffold/views/handlebars/edit.html.hbs.ejs#L15), note that `this` is used to pass the current rending context to the subview.

[Here is the same thing done in jade](https://github.com/mde/geddy/blob/master/gen/scaffold/views/jade/edit.html.jade.ejs#L11), and [again in ejs](https://github.com/mde/geddy/blob/master/gen/scaffold/views/ejs/edit.html.ejs.ejs#L15).